# Show text inside polygon on Leaflet map

Tags: polygon, leaflet, labeling, error

When I try to label the polygon on my Leaflet map I always get the error:

> t is undefined

I am trying to do it as shown below:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <style>
        #mapid { height: 600px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mapid"></div>
<script>

    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: 'your.mapbox.project.id',
        accessToken: 'your.mapbox.public.access.token'
    }).addTo(mymap);
    var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(mymap);
    var polygon = L.polygon([
        [51.509, -0.08],
        [51.503, -0.06],
        [51.51, -0.047]
    ]).addTo(mymap);
    var label = new L.Label()
    label.setContent("static label")
    label.setLatLng(polygon.getBounds().getCenter())
    mymap.showLabel(label);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to show some text inside the polygon. I've tried to accomplish it using label but unable to do it.

Comment: Your header loads `test.js` - what's that?

Comment: yes it load it onctains leaflet label.js code

Comment: please post a example if u already have one

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you seem to be using leaflet 1.0 you can use the tooltip to attach text to a polygon. No need for a separate label plugin or anything. Just this:

```
 polygon.bindTooltip("My polygon",
   {permanent: true, direction:"center"}
  ).openTooltip()
```

For more info: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#tooltip

Comment: i am getting this error polygon.bindTooltip is not a function can u please say whats wrong

Comment: You'd probably get that error with an earlier version of leaflet. Are you sure you are using 1.0 when you get that error?

Answer (score 4):

```
polygon.bindTooltip("My polygon", {permanent: true, direction:"center"})
```

removed code: .openTooltip()

Answer (score 0):

thankfully, you may find a dedicated solution now, here: [leaflet.textpath](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.TextPath).
i have just installed it, looks good and seems promissing.